# How to integrate Node.js Server in My cocod2d-x (C++) Game

Tags: node.js, cocos2d-x, multiplayer

I am new in Multiplayer Game Development, I have already developed a offline game and now I want to make it a multiplayer, so with help of my friend we create a server side script in node.js, but I don't know how to integrate this in my c++ project,

I've googled but, can't find anything helpful.
anybody can suggest any tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a big open-ended question.  As Allern suggests there are a lot of things that you can do with networked programs that can extend it well beyond that of a single user game.  For instance in my current game there is an access to a version welcome page in html.  There are file downloads for campaign/user maps and there are connections to Firebase for leaderboards and other networked resources like ads.

However, I suspect you are referring to the communications between a number of separate user machines all synchronized to keep them coordinated.  For this you will need to write some serialization code to transmit to and receive packets from the central server.  Typically a serialization package like [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) will be needed to move information from your data structures to a packet and the reverse.

You might also require communication/network software to asynchronously send and receive those packets (this may be included in whatever game engine you might be using). [Boost.asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/) might help otherwise.  There are numerous other networking packages and libraries all the way down to the bare-bones unix/POSIX calls (or Windows OS calls).

You will also need software on the server side to log users in, deal with players disconnecting and doing the main work of passing the game packets around.  This software may also implement the logic of your game (game rules) and might do saves on the data if you want users to be able to play the game in multiple sessions (like a big dungeon crawl). There might be packages out there that do most of the server side stuff.  If so, please post what you find out.

Cocos2dx does have some networking software built in but it isn't very functional as far as I'm concerned.  It does have facilities to display web pages and download files fairly easy but the async communication seems a little weak.  You can try the Network module in the [API Docs](https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/api-ref/cplusplus/v3x/db/d3a/group__network.html) which may have what you are looking for.

Since the type of game and how you want to implement your player interaction will dictate how the software is to be built I'm afraid this answer is a little vague.  Good luck.  Share your insights.

Answer (score -1):

you can use public tools , as a sample is websocket,it can support C++ and javasc